# How to gracefully cancel `gpiod_line_event_wait`?

Tags: c++, libgpiod

I'm facing an issue with the libgpiod, I guess there is a solution but it's not clear for me. I want to create sometimes a worker that will listen some gpio chip lines events and be able to stop it.

I spawn the worker thread in something like that:

```cpp
std::jthread([this]() {
    gpiod_line_event event;
    while (is_running) {
        gpiod_line_event_wait(line, NULL);
        gpiod_line_event_read(line, &event);
        if (event.event_type == GPIOD_LINE_EVENT_RISING_EDGE) {
            std::cout << "GPIOD_LINE_EVENT_RISING_EDGE\n";
        } else if (event.event_type == GPIOD_LINE_EVENT_FALLING_EDGE) {
            std::cout << "GPIOD_LINE_EVENT_FALLING_EDGE\n";
        }
    }
});
```

That let me stuck in `gpiod_line_event_wait`. Is there a good way to cancel it and continue properly?

I tried to close the chip and release the line. I also tried to set the line value but nothing worked. I've seen that constant `GPIOD_CTXLESS_EVENT_POLL_RET_STOP` but I don't really understand if it can help me and how I should use it.

Edit: of course I could also use the timeout parameter and check if I should quit the execution sometimes but I'm looking for something else.

Edit:
Actually there is a pretty simple solution. `libgpiod` provides the `gpiod_line_request_get_fd` that return a file descriptor for the line.

Once you've that, you can create 2 `pollfd` structures, the line-request will have events `POLLIN` and `POLLPRI` and the second will be a simple channel with the event you want. Then we can just call ppoll with these arguments and trigger the channel whenever we want to stop the worker.

An implementation could be:

```
int wait_until(int fd, int channel, int64_t timeout_ns)
{
        struct pollfd pfds[2];
        int ret;

        memset(&pfds, 0, sizeof(pfds));
        pfds[0].fd = fd;
        pfds[0].events = POLLIN | POLLPRI;
        pfds[1].fd = channel;
        pfds[1].events = POLLIN | POLLERR;

        ret = poll_fds(pfds, 2, timeout_ns);
        if (ret >= 1 && pfds[1].revents != 0)
                return 2;
        return ret;
}

static int
poll_fds(struct pollfd *pfds, uint8_t len, int64_t timeout_ns)
{
        struct timespec ts;
        int ret;

        if (timeout_ns >= 0) {
                ts.tv_sec = timeout_ns / 1000000000ULL;
                ts.tv_nsec = timeout_ns % 1000000000ULL;
        }

        ret = ppoll(pfds, len, timeout_ns < 0 ? NULL : &ts, NULL);
        if (ret < 0)
                return -1;
        else if (ret == 0)
                return 0;

        return 1;
}
```

Comment: https://libgpiod-dlang.dpldocs.info/gpiod.gpiod_line_event_wait.html - from the docs it seems that you can pass some timeout as a second argument, so yes. Why this solution seems to be not good for you?

Comment: It would be handy to be able to cancel without periodically fall into a timeout and redo. If I can, I prefer to defer that kind of responsibility to the library. I don't want to respawn to often with a small interval or have a delay with a big one. As the library seems to work with an event loop, I guess that we can trigger it somehow and handle an error. That's what I'm looking for. However, I hope for some suggestions, but I'll choose the timeout way if nothing else is possible. Thx @pptaszni